# How to take a screen capture on Motorola Xoom?

Tags: android, screen-capture, motorola, xoom, samsung-mobile

I want to take a screen capture on Motorola Xoom.

In Samsung Galaxy S-I you can do it by:

start pressing the HOME and immediately press BACK.

In Samsung Galaxy S-II/III you can do it by:

start pressing the HOME and immediately press on OFF/Lock button.

But how can I do it on Motorola Xoom (Without using Eclipse tools)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link detailing how.

[How to take a Xoom Screenshot](http://letmebuzz.com/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-motorola-xoom/)

Ps. I think you have to use the eclipse tools.

Comment: Ya you right. can be done only with SDK tools

Comment: Power+Volume down works well too.

Comment: Although, it may take some practice before you can successfully press Power + Volume Down at just the right time so it triggers the screenshot, rather than either of the two operations...

Answer (score 9):

You can now take the screen shot (in ICS and after) by pressing Volume Down + Power at the same time for a second. 
Worked fine with 4.1.1 on a Xoom WiFi.

Comment: Make sure you hold it down longer than you'd think, I took about 3-4 seconds for my xoom to actually take the shot.

Comment: That's the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Power button + volume reduce button.. works well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Eclipse tools or you can tools the SMG SDK (free) that enables video capture for any application via the capture of OpenGl commands (very lightweight, can run in the background all the time)

www.seemegaming.com